# Solving A Single Linear Equation with Three Variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an equation that looks like this:

```
0.21r + 0.71g + 0.07b = 188
```

I need to determine the values of r, g, & b...Is this possible with only one equation? The idea is to convert a grayscale image that was created with a specified filter into a color image...

Comment: As was pointed out in a comment below, you'll need to specify what values $r$, $g$, and $b$ can take.  Are they positive integers?

Comment: Why do you think it is possible to recover full colour from a black-and-white image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to work at the simultaneous version of Dirichlet's theorem on Diophantine approximation, it would be smarter to construct the giant table of color-to-gray+error values, entries of which are of 5 element vectors the form $$(r,g,b, \text{gray} = \text{round}(0.21r + 0.71g + 0.07b), \text{amount rounded away})$$
and then, for each gray value, pick the entry in the table with that gray value and the least amount rounded away.

What this will give you is a riotously terrible inverse function since an entire plane in RGB space (perpendicular to the white-black axis) is being mapped to only one color.  The color will jump around randomly from gray level to gray level.  The likelihood of generating the color that was originally used is approximately zero.

**However**, if your filter is (nearly) monochromatic and you *know* the hue of your filter, you would do better to try inversion in HSV or HSL color spaces.  Set the hue to match your filter, pick the saturation (from gray to hue at constant brightness) that you like.  This is entirely aesthetic.  A good interference filter should only pass totally saturated light, but you may find that less easy to understand for blue or red since the eye's photopic response to blue is poor, to red is okay, and to green is strong -- mixing in some gray keeping constant brightness may make the interpretation of resulting images better.  If no human will try to interpret the results, then set the saturation to maximum.  Finally take your value from the gray level.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV for a discussion of the HSV and HSL color spaces.  This page also includes conversions to RGB from these color spaces (which I assume you want for use in some sort of display).

Converting from wavelength to hue is not as straightforward.  If you can do with "close enough", then use the CIE color space (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_color_space ) and **using the display you will use for final output** visually match a sample of hue (100% saturation, lightness = 50% or value near 100%).  (For instance, open the CIE image in a paint program and use an eyedropper tool at the right place in the image, then use the program's information to get either HSV, HSL, or RGB (which you will then have to convert).)  Caveats:  No finite mix-in display device (includes printers) can reproduce the entire CIE color space -- it can only generate a polygonal region inside the space.  If your output device has not been spectrally calibrated, then the color you pick won't "be" the color it should be for that wavelength.  The result displayed or printed elsewhere very likely will not match the color of the original light.  Selection of whitepoint matters (but usually only a little).  No care has been taken to handle variations in spectral eye response across humans (not everyone is using exactly the same cones).  This is a reasonable article on most of this:  http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/

Comment: why will the "color jump around randomly"? i've composed a histogram of the image in question using a quantization frequency of 256 so as to lock luminance values to increments of 1/256...their( pixels ) values aren't random...my task now is to relate this grayscale( histogram equalized ) image back to rgb color space...i agree of course that i will not be able to reproduce the color from grayscale...how might i scale my rgb image after histogram equalization?

Comment: @P. Avery: I believe there is an adequate description of how to proceed after histogram equalization starting with the bold "However" in the answer.

Comment: I agree thanks.

Comment: @P. Avery: There are (at least) 256 RGB values that map to the gray level 16, including (0,18,48) blue, and (76,0,0) red.  The point in the RGB space closest to the plane of graylevel 16 is the blue (15,2,163) (with residual 0.02).  The point in RGB space closest to the plane of graylevel 17 is the magenta (61,0,61) (with residual 0.01).  The point in RGB space closest to the plane of graylevel 18 is the red (78,1,13) (with ersidual 0.0).  I.e., the colors jump around randomly because there's some point nearest the plane, but that point could be any color.

Comment: I see...the wiki article you linked above was very helpful in understanding the RGB gamut. Now I'm working on mapping my RGB values to HSV such that I can associate a gray level value with a specific hue and chroma...

Comment: @P.Avery:  Unless you know the color of the original light, you have no information to select a hue or chroma.  The only information in your signal is the value or lightness.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. The map that takes $(r,g,b)\mapsto 0.21r+0.71g+0.07b$ sends a plane of points to each output value. You can specify any two of $r$, $g$, and $b$, and there will be a value of the third such that the point maps to a specified output.

Comment: This is true in general, but I wonder if there is more that can be done in this specific situation since we are not dealing with $\mathbb{R}$ but rather $\mathbb{U}_{255}$ (at least partially since the coefficients are given in hundredths).

Comment: Same problem exists. You're just restricting to integer lattice in the portion of the plane that lies in a cube.

Comment: For a specific example, note that if $(r,g,b)$ is a solution, so is $(r-k,g,b+3k)$ for each integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

If $r$, $g$, and $b$ are real numbers, then the answer is no.  There are more than one set of values of $r$, $g$, and $b$ that will satisfy your equation.  Three examples that quickly come to mind are: $(r,g,b)$=$(188/0.21,0,0)$, $(0,188/0.71,0)$, and $(0,0,188/0.07)$.